# How to add particle system to ios app without black background

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit

I added the following CAEmitterLayer with these parameters which I have reduced but still don't get the desired effect.  Id like to have fewer snowflakes and have them float down slowly, but there are too many and they fall too fast despite my reductions in the parameters of birthrate and velocity/yAcceleration.

Here is the code:

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)aRect{

    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:aRect])) {

        //set ref to the layer
        fireEmitter = (CAEmitterLayer*)self.layer; //2
        //configure the emitter layer
        fireEmitter.emitterPosition = CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width / 4, - 10); // 2
        fireEmitter.emitterZPosition = 10; // 3
        fireEmitter.emitterSize = CGSizeMake(self.bounds.size.width, 0); // 4
        fireEmitter.emitterShape = kCAEmitterLayerSphere; // 5

        CAEmitterCell* fire = [CAEmitterCell emitterCell];
        fire.scale = 0.1;
        fire.scaleRange = 0.2;
        fire.emissionRange = (CGFloat)M_PI_2;
        fire.birthRate = 2;
        fire.lifetime = 5.0;
        fire.velocity = 30;
        fire.velocityRange = 50;
        fire.yAcceleration = 50;

        fire.contents = (id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"snow.png"] CGImage];
        [fire setName:@"fire"];

        fireEmitter.emitterCells = [NSArray arrayWithObject:fire];
        [self setIsEmitting:YES];

    }
    return self;

}
```

Here are the results:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sprite Kit views cannot be made transparent. But Sprite Kit isn't the only way to get particle effects in iOS. Look into CAEmitterLayer — that's more appropriate for mixing with UIKit.

Comment: Ok Im using this tut (http://www.raywenderlich.com/6063/uikit-particle-systems-in-ios-5-tutorial) where we create a UIView with a + (Class) layerClass method to return a CAEmitterLayer.  I configure the emitter here and then we are told to make an outlet in our existing view controller and connect it to this class' view.  If Im using storyboards, do I just add that view programmatically instead?

Comment: Thx, I updated my code and an image, Id like to have fewer snowflakes and have them float down slowly, but there are too many and they fall too fast despite my reductions in the parameters of birthrate and velocity/yAcceleration.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Make a transparent background.png to display the particle effect on... or set black background to a transparent alpha like; 0.1
Example;

```
background.alpha = 0.1;
```

I hope you can work it out.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is very late but it might help someone.

I believe this might do the trick, this will slowly fade them.

```
fire.alphaSpeed = -0.15
```

I'd kill the yacceleration, as it'll make your birthrate seem higher.